# WPF - command between UserControls

Tags: wpf

I would like to bind command to my user control:

```
<MyUserControl MyCommand="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

**MyUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
    {
        public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(MyCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCommandProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));


        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<Button Content="CLICK" 
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MyCommand}"/>
```

**Parent UserControl:**

```
 <view:MyUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MyCommand="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

When I click on button, command dont execute. Thanks for advices

Comment: 2 lines of xaml markup, torn from context isn't a [mcve]. many wpf issues happen from incorrect wiring of view and viewmodel. so please make your example complete and reproducable

Comment: The third parameter of `DependencyProperty.Register` must be the type that registers the property, i.e. `typeof(MyUserControl)`.

Comment: What is "ToggleButtons"? What's the actual name of the type where the command property is defined? And how is your actual command to be executed defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this issue but I cannot, my findings is some time you mat be missing datacontext.

**MainWindow**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            testCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeCanExecute);
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private ICommand testCommand { get; set; }
        private bool canExecute = true;
        public bool CanExecute
        {
            get
            {
                return this.canExecute;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.canExecute == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.canExecute = value;
            }
        }

        public ICommand TestCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return testCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                testCommand = value;
            }
        }
        public void ChangeCanExecute(object obj)
        {
            canExecute = !canExecute;
        }
    }
```